# How can I check that a MEF CompositionContainer does not maintain a reference to a non-shared part?

Tags: .net-4.5, mef

I am using MEF in a WPF application.  I use MEF to create view model objects for my views, and am interested in avoiding memory leaks by ensuring that the MEF `CompositionContainer` does not keep references to my view model objects.

I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8787982/mef-keeps-reference-of-nonshared-idisposable-parts-not-allowing-them-to-be-coll) and its answers.  I carefully avoid using `IDisposable`, since [it doesn't "play nicely" with WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=idisposable+wpf).

For debug purposes, I would like to write some code that *asserts that an object has not been added to the `CompositionContainer`*.  This would ensure that I haven't made a subtle change to a view model class that means that it is now not properly being released.

Here is some sample code.  How can I implement `AssertNotInContainer`?  Note that in this example it would be trivial to dispose of `exportLifetimeContext` properly.  However, in my more complex scenario I want to be able to rely on the garbage collector rather than `IDisposable`, since [it is hard to determine the lifetime of WPF objects and their associated view models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10583810/why-does-wpf-not-use-idisposable-and-what-are-the-ramifications) (attached by the `DataContext`).

```
namespace Demo
{
    using System;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.Diagnostics;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(new ApplicationCatalog());

            MyOwnerClass demo = container.GetExport<MyOwnerClass>().Value;

            // Not going to dispose this...
            ExportLifetimeContext<MyLittleClass> exportLifetimeContext = demo.Factory.CreateExport();

            // Note that I don't dispose of exportLifetimeContext, since I know that if MyLittleClass obeys
            // the proper rules, it won't be added to the container anyway, and exportLifetimeContext.Dispose()
            // will do nothing anyway.
            MyLittleClass part = exportLifetimeContext.Value;

            // I wan't this to assert that part is not referenced in container.
            container.AssertNotInContainer(part);

            // This is a hacky way that I can confirm that MyLittleClass isn't referenced by the container.
            // This causes "Finalized." to be sent to the console.
            GC.Collect();
        
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [Export]
    public class MyOwnerClass
    {
        [Import]
        public ExportFactory<MyLittleClass> Factory { get; set; }
    }

    [Export]
    [PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
    public class MyLittleClass
    {
        ~MyLittleClass()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Finalized.");
        }
    }

    public static class MefHelper
    {
        [Conditional("DEBUG")]
        public static void AssertNotInContainer(this CompositionContainer container, object part)
        {
            // What code should I write here?
            bool isInContainer = false /* ??? */;

            if (isInContainer)
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(
                    "Part does not meet rules for not being added to CompositionContainer.  You have a leak!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## MEF Part Lifetime

The MEF documentation includes a useful, though out-of-date, [page explaining the lifetime of objects created by MEF](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Parts%20Lifetime).  It says the following:

> We believe that .Net Garbage Collector is the best thing to rely on for proper clean up. However, we also need to provider a container that has a deterministic behavior. Thus, the container will not hold references to parts it creates unless one of the following is true:
>
> - The part is marked as Shared
> - The part implements `IDisposable`
> - One or more imports is configured to allow recomposition

Comment: I'm not sure I got it, but to check whether a part is in the container or not you can simply iterate through Container.Catalog.Parts.

Comment: @AndrasSebö, I think that confirms that the part has been discovered.  But that would be the case even before MEF has created an instance of the part.  I want to check that, after creating an instance, MEF has not retained a reference to the part in the container.  I'll edit my question to include a link to a page that explains a bit more about part lifetimes.