# Do WPF Windows Dispose() their DataContexts?

Tags: .net, wpf, resource-management

If I set the `DataContext` of a `Window` to something that implements `IDisposable`, will it be `Dispose()`d when the `Window` is closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No!

WPF doesn't really use the `IDisposable` interface at all—and it can be a bit tricky to write WPF code that relies on it.

Consider using something like [Caliburn Micro](https://github.com/caliburn-micro/caliburn.micro), an MVVM framework that supports matching views and view models (assigned to `DataContext`) and *does* support automatically calling `Dispose()`. Without knowing the specifics of your situation, though, CM may be a bit more than you need in your scenario.

If you're interested in *why* WPF doesn't use `IDisposable`, there are several posts on StackOverflow [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254271/when-can-i-dispose-an-idisposable-wpf-control-e-g-windowsformshost) that address this. Although this discusses why controls themselves aren't disposed, the rationale applies to the `DataContext` too, since it's just an inherited property of the control.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up just cleaning up resources when the `Closed` event of the `Window` fires.